# Signing GET HTTP Requests to Amazon Elasticsearch Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-elasticsearch

I need to call "Signing GET HTTP Requests to Amazon Elasticsearch Service" using lambda function.

I have already tried `http` package and it's working fine in `http` request

```
http.get(`http://search-"my_ES_service_name"-xxxxxxxxxxx-6fa27gkk4v3dugykj46tzsipbu.xx-xxxx-x.es.amazonaws.com/${event['index']}/doc/_search/?q=${event['keyParam']}`, 
  function(res) { 
    var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(d) {
            body += d;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            context.succeed(JSON.parse(body.replace(/\n|\r/g, ""))); //Remove and newline/linebreak chars
        });
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Error: " + e.message);
    context.done(null, 'FAILURE');
  });
```

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  var region = 'xx-xxxx-x';
  var domain = 'http://search-"my_ES_service_name"-xxxxxxxxxxx-6fa27gkk4v3dugykj46tzsipbu.xx-xxxx-x.es.amazonaws.com';
  var index = event['index'];
  var type = `_doc/_search`;

  var endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint(domain);
  var request = new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint, region);
  request.method = 'GET';
  request.path += index + '/' + type+'?q=_doc_key_here:_doc_key_value';
  request.headers['host'] = domain;
  > e.g. URL genrate like: http://search-"my_ES_service_name"-xxxxxxxxxxx-6fa27gkk4v3dugykj46tzsipbu.xx-xxxx-x.es.amazonaws.com/node-test/doc/_search/?q=user_name:johndoe

  var credentials = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');
  var signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(request, 'es');
  signer.addAuthorization(credentials, new Date());

  var client = new AWS.HttpClient();
  client.handleRequest(request, null, function(response) {
    console.log("response: ",response.statusCode);
    var responseBody = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      responseBody += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function (chunk) {
      console.log('Response body: ' + responseBody);
      context.succeed(responseBody)
    });
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
    context.done(error);
  });
}
```

when I'm trying to call "Signing GET HTTP Requests" using above function, then it's thrown me the following error:

> response:  400 Bad Request

Comment: request.path += index + '/' + type+'?q=_doc_key_here:_doc_key_value'; is that correct that looks like a copy and paste from docs. But I would guess if you are not actually passing a correct query you are going to end up with a bad Request.

Comment: Hey @JamesKn, Thank you for your response
I've passed it correct form like `myIndex/_search/?q=user_name:johndoe`

Comment: But it always throws an **bad Request**, and this same URL is working fine in `http` request

Comment: What permissions do you have on the role for the lambda ? does it have permissions to Elasticsearch  you give it some something silly wide like {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Action": [
"es:*"
],
"Effect": "Allow",
"Resource": "*"
}
]
}

Comment: Assuming code is sorted then you basically have permissions in role / security groups are good.

Comment: @JamesKn, I've already attached above policy in my Elasticsearch and also give full permission to the role of lambda

Comment: My concern is if the `Http` package works fine then why **Signing GET HTTP Requests to Amazon Elasticsearch Service** not work?

Comment: update you answer with all the extra details and then I would debug console out more of your process in the code and post that to the question. This should hopefully help others highlight why you have an issue. This should also 100% check you have a problem in your code / security.

Answer (score 0):

Only one thing is missing here, I have added `encodeURI()` in **request** and it works fine for me

```
var index = event['index'];
var type = `_doc/_search?q=_doc_key_here:_doc_key_value`;
request.method = 'GET';
request.path += index + '/' + encodeURI(type);
```

I hope it will help other guys

Thanks